# Unable to initialize device PRN when using print.exe

Tags: batch-file, printing

I see that this has come up a few times before, but there does not seem to be a straight answer / solution. Or at least, not one that has worked for me.

Here is the script I am using:

```
@echo off

cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs -a -r IP_10.121.38.191 -h 10.121.38.191

cscript "c:\windows\system32\printing_admin_scripts\en-us\prndrvr.vbs" -a -m "HP Color LaserJet M553 PCL 6" -h "d:\driver\" -i "d:\driver\hpmacf2a_x64.inf"

cscript "c:\windows\system32\printing_admin_scripts\en-us\prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "Printer" -m "HP Color LaserJet M553 PCL 6" -r IP_10.121.38.191

manage-bde -protectors c: -get > c:\bitlocker.txt

print /d:printer c:\bitlocker.txt
```

End result:
"Unable to initialize device PRN"

I am stuck and dont know where to look from here.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a printer connected to the parallel port?

Comment: No, i created the port "IP_10.121.38.191" to connect to a network printer. 
Keep in mind, the printer is not connected to a computer or print server.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the quote old tool `print.exe` supports anything other than parallel port printers; perhaps an additional tool is needed to map the network printer to an `LPT?:` port…

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

VBS

```
Dim objShell, objFolder, objFile
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("c:\")
Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("bitlocker.txt")
objFile.InvokeVerb("Print")
```